# C# Cassandra - Find And Modify one Row

Tags: c#, cassandra

Using the C# interface, how do I lock 1 row in Cassandra, update it, and then unlock it? Until the lock is released, no other process on any machine or threads on the same machine should be able to read the row.

Comment: There is no system in Cassandra for locking a row. Cassandra is optimized for concurrent and distributed writes and a distributed lock would be antithetical to the design of the system.

Comment: You may want to investigate CAS operations which may produce some of the properties you desire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't -- the Lock concept does not exists in Cassandra -- you have to perform this operation in your application using a distributed lock. For the purpose you can give a look at ZooKeeper, Hazelcast or Memcached -- you can achieve the goal with any of these -- I'm not into c# world but I see that each of these products provides a c# client. You can also take a look at Cages, a library based on ZooKeeper created just for the goal (http://ria101.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/locking-and-transactions-over-cassandra-using-cages/)

Alternatively you could implement your distributed-lock using lightweight transactions (http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_ltwt_transaction_c.html). It's just an idea but you could have a locking CF. For each ROW you need to lock you put an entry into this locking-table (with Serial CL) using IF NOT EXISTS clause -- if you "acquired the lock" (cassandra will tell you as the result of the operation) you can  start working. One advantage I see in this model is that you can write your lock entry with a TTL -- if you imagine your operation would last maximum X you can put a TTL on the row of 2X, so if your machine dies before removing the entry from the lock table ("releasing the lock") Cassandra will do this for you.

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: The lightweight transaction appears to do what I need. Thank you for sharing.